# create a union type in typescript with methods of a class

Tags: typescript, ngredux

I am looking at some legacy code and they have created all the redux reducers as instance methods of a class:

```
@Injectable()
export class PeopleActions {
    constructor(private ngRedux: NgRedux<any>) {}

    add() {
      this.ngRedux.dispatch({ADD, payload: {foo: 'bar;});
    }

    remove() {
      this.ngRedux.dispatch({Remove, payload: {foo: 'bar;});
    }
    // etc.
```

I would normally create these as sepreate functions

```
export function add { // etc.}
export function remove { // etc.}
```

And then create a union:

```
type MyActions = add | remove;
```

Can I somehow create a union of the class instance methods?

Comment: You want to create the `MyActions` type? Should it be a union of the names of the methods or the signatures of the methods ? Because the syntax is not valid as is in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a union of all keys in the type you can use `keyof`

```
type MyActions = keyof PeopleActions; // "add" | "remove"
```

If the class also has public fields that are not methods and you want to filter those out you can use a conditional type:

```
type ExtractFunctionKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends Function ? P : never}[keyof T]
type MyActions = ExtractFunctionKeys<PeopleActions>; // "add" | "remove"
```

Comment: this is great.  Totally forgot about `keyof`.